# How to include directives in a template in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have 2 components,
    1)Table.component
    2)Dashboard.component

I want to use table template in dashboard component and for that i declared a selec tor in table component as

```
   selector: '[tables-basic]',
```

Is there anything to include in table.template?

and i imported the table component in dashboard module and i declared the component name  and put the selector in dashboard component as

```
 <tables-basic></tables-basic>
```

But i got the error as

```
    1. If 'tables-basic' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'tables-basic' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schema' of this component to suppress this message. ("      <div id="tabs2c" class="tab-content bg-info-light">
            <div id = "tab2">
            [ERROR ->]<tables-basic></tables-basic>
              </div>
<!--
```

Am i missed any thing.Can anyone please suggest help.
my uielement module.ts,

```
   import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule,ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AlertModule, TooltipModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';
import { ButtonsModule, DropdownModule, PaginationModule  } from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';
import { DataTableDirectives } from 'angular2-datatable/datatable';
import { Ng2TableModule } from 'ng2-table';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { WidgetModule } from '../layout/widget/widget.module';
import { UtilsModule } from '../layout/utils/utils.module';
import { JqSparklineModule } from '../components/sparkline/sparkline.module';
import 'parsleyjs';
//import { TablesBasic } from './basic/tables-basic.component';
import { TablesDynamic } from './dynamic/tables-dynamic.component';
import { SearchPipe } from './dynamic/pipes/search-pipe';
import {Ng2PaginationModule} from 'ng2-pagination';


export const routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'basic', pathMatch: 'full'},
  // {path: 'basic', component: TablesBasic},
  {path: 'dynamic', component: TablesDynamic},
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    // Components / Directives/ Pipes
    DataTableDirectives,
   // TablesBasic,
    TablesDynamic,
    SearchPipe
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    Ng2PaginationModule,
    HttpModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    JqSparklineModule,
    FormsModule,
    AlertModule,
    TooltipModule,
    ButtonsModule,
    DropdownModule,
    PaginationModule,
    WidgetModule,
    UtilsModule,
    Ng2TableModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  schemas:  [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
})
export default class UiElementsModule {
  static routes = routes;
}
```

Comment: share your module file code here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['tables-basic' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40458135/tables-basic-is-an-angular-component-then-verify-that-it-is-part-of-this-modu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either change the selector to

```
selector: 'tables-basic',
```

or the element to

```
 <div tables-basic></div tables-basic>
```

(where `div` can be any element)

`selector: '[tables-basic]',` is an attribute selector and requires a matching attribute not an element name.

Comment: It seems i did a mistake and i changed the selector and then i am facing this error

Comment: Error: Type TablesBasic is part of the declarations of 2 modules: AppModule and UiElementsModule! Please consider moving TablesBasic to a higher module that imports AppModule and UiElementsModule.

Comment: Create a new `NgModule` for the directive, add the directive to `declarations: []` and `exports: []` of the new `NgModule`, and then add this module to `imports: [MySharedModule]` in every module where you want to use it. You can't add a component, directive, or pipe to `declarations: []` of more than one module.

Comment: Sorry i am completly new to angular2,i have appmodule. As main module as you said ,do i need to create one more module?

Comment: If you only have one module, then I can't explain what causes your error message. Actually you mentioned UiElementsModule. Perhaps you only need to add the directive to `declarations: []` and `exports: []` of this module and add this module to `imports: []` of `AppModule`.

Comment: Ohk i have tables module,dashboardmodule and appmodule as main module....i am declaring tablecomponent in tables module as well as in dashboard module and there the error occured

Comment: Then only declare it in `tables` module and then add `tables` module to `imports: []` of `dashboard` module.

Comment: Soory i clearly understood now,i have ui elements module where i declared my table component and i want to use the table component in dashboard module which is not possible since we cant declare in 2 modules,so i will try to import my ui elements module in appmodule

Comment: Gunter,i got a type error while importing my uielementmodule and i attached the screen shot,can you pls check it.

Comment: `@NgModule({...}) **export** class UiElementsModule {}`

Comment: I edited my code with uielemnetsmodule.ts and i even put export

Comment: Remove the `default` it doesn't work with `AoT` AFAIK.